# Error on opening PDF that is generated by JSPDF Image HTML2Canvas in Acrobat reader

Tags: javascript, vue.js

1. Generated PDF working with All browser
2. We can't open in Acrobat reader. Getting error "An error exist on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. please contact the person who created the pdf document to correct the problem."

Pdf file not opening in Adobe Acrobat Reader but opening in Chrome. Here is my code:

```
downloadPDFGraphs() {
      if (this.onPDFDownload) {
        this.$emit("onPDFDownload");
        return;
      }

      this.download("pdf");
    },
    download(type) {
      const todayDate = moment().format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss").toUpperCase();
      let container = document.querySelector("#" + this.downloadId);
      let filename = this.titleChart + "_" + todayDate + "." + type;
      if (this.specificSiteId && this.specificSiteId.length > 0) {
        filename =
          this.titleChart +
          "_" +
          todayDate +
          "_" +
          getSiteID(this.specificSiteId[0]) +
          "." +
          type;
      }
      html2canvas(container, {
        allowTaint: true,
        logging: false,
        height: !this.zoomGraphValueChild ? 400 : 550,
        scrollY: -window.scrollY,
        useCORS: true,
        scrollX: -window.scrollX,
        onclone: (document) => {
          if (this.specificSiteId && this.specificSiteId.length > 0) {
            if (
              document.querySelector("#" + this.downloadId + " .title-date") !=
              null
            ) {
              document
                .querySelector("#" + this.downloadId + " .title-date")
                .append("_" + this.getSiteID(this.specificSiteId[0]));
            } else {
              document
                .querySelector(
                  "#" + this.downloadId + " .card-management-title"
                )
                .append("_" + this.getSiteID(this.specificSiteId[0]));
            }
          }
          document
            .querySelectorAll("#" + this.downloadId + " .custom-tooltip")
            .forEach((element) => {
              element.remove();
            });
          document
            .querySelectorAll("#" + this.downloadId + " .apexcharts-toolbar")
            .forEach((element) => {
              element.remove();
            });
          document
            .querySelectorAll("#" + this.downloadId + " .remove-elem-download")
            .forEach((element) => {
              element.remove();
            });
          document
            .querySelectorAll("#" + this.downloadId + " .remove-zoom-icons")
            .forEach((element) => {
              element.remove();
            });
          document
            .querySelectorAll("#" + this.downloadId + " .nav-item")
            .forEach((element) => {
              const ele = element.querySelector(".nav-link.active");
              if (!ele) {
                element.remove();
              }
            });

          if (this.downloadId === "studyMaps") {
            let dateTime = document.createElement("div");
            dateTime.classList.add("ml-15");
            dateTime.textContent = todayDate;
            document.querySelector("#" + this.downloadId).append(dateTime);
          } else {
            if (this.downloadId === "completion-data") {
              let dateTime = document.createElement("div");
              dateTime.classList.add("ml-15");
              dateTime.textContent = todayDate;
              document.querySelector("#" + this.downloadId).append(dateTime);
              if (document.querySelectorAll(".table-content").length > 0) {
                document.querySelectorAll(".table-content")[0].className =
                  "remove-overflow";
              }
              if (document.querySelectorAll(".rtl-display").length > 0) {
                document.querySelectorAll(".rtl-display")[0].className =
                  "ltr-display";
              }
            } else if(this.downloadId === "daily-sensor-compliance"){
              let dateTime = document.createElement("div");
              dateTime.classList.add("ml-15");
              dateTime.textContent = todayDate;
              document.querySelector("#" + this.downloadId).append(dateTime);
            } else {
              document.querySelector("#" + this.downloadId).innerHTML +=
                '<div class="ml-15">' + todayDate + "</div>";
            }
          }
        },
      }).then((canvas) => {
        if (type === "pdf") {
          const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          let pdf = new jspdf("p", "mm", "a4");
          const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
          const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
          const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
          pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0, pdfWidth - 5, pdfHeight);
          pdf.save(filename);
        } else if (type === "png") {
          let link = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.download = filename;
          link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          link.target = "_blank";
          link.click();
        }
      });
    },
```

[Please find the error from Acrobat reader see attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UBNv.png)

Comment: Have you tried opening this file in some other PDF reader software?

Comment: Can you post the PDF ?